Connections vertically and horizontally











quarter
blow
kill
bill


two
punched through
decree
pound


sent
law
executed
passed


draw
too
cuff
cent



The goal is to rearrange the sixteen words above so that the four words in each row, AND the four words in each column, have some sort of connection.
Here is a barebones interactive version (created with the help of ChatGPT)
Warning: some of the categories and word fits are a bit weak.  It would be cool to see someone create a better version of this puzzle.

This is the second time I've seen this attempted here, but the first one is still not fully solved, if anyone is interested...

@Stiv:  I was not aware, thanks for the link!

"Warning: some of the categories and word fits are a bit weak. It would be cool to see someone create a better version of this puzzle." - I'm afraid I would have to agree with that.  Some are just plain wrong, e.g. rot13('qen' vf cebabhaprq qvssreragyl gb 'qenj', fb gur 'j' vf pyrneyl abg fvyrag.) and none of the groups are without flaws.  However, I appreciate how hard it must be to create an 8-way connecting wall, so well done for the attempt!

@HappyDog Interesting point:  I guess I consider sin/sine to be a silent e, although you're right something like by/bye is "truly silent".

Digression, but the technical term is a split digraph, i.e. a digraph (two-character phoneme) where the two characters are split across another letter (or letters).  sine is actually made up of three phonemes - s, i_e (the split digraph) and n.  You therefore can't say the e is silent.  You could maybe say it's 'unvoiced' but I'm not sure even that is correct as it does contribute to the sound of the word.

Great interactive little puzzle :)
The final solution is:

 

Rows:

 1. 2 out of 3 homophones
 2. hit
 3. lethal punishment
 4. creating government rules

Columns:

 1. money
 2. ends in double letter
 3. silent w
 4. completed

